# responding with index.html in express and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, create-react-app

I have an express app where inside it has a create-react-app. when the user goes to root url I want to show the index.html present in create-react-app public folder. Here is my code for index.js in express app

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get('/',function(req,res){


});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

Here is my project directory

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `sendFile()` you can do something like this:

```
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, './client/public', 'index.html'));
});
app.use('/', router);
```

I'm using the path because depending how you start your app it might break with just the relative path.

Comment: Im getting this error : Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/sriram/Desktop/public/index.html'

Comment: Yes I will update the answer it is how the path is used, given your project structure, see the updated answer now

Comment: Yes this is working my title got changed to React App, but i didnt get the body of it , is it because of bundle.js or something related . Im using create-react-app by the way inside codit(express app)

Comment: As I can see from your folder structure picture you haven't built your app, make sure to run `npm run build` in your React app

Answer (score 2):

You need this line: `app.use(express.static('public'))`. See here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: thats it? where should I add it

Comment: and how to get the path for the index.html

Comment: for now, just add it in place of your current `app.get` block. that should be all you need to serve index.html, because that basically tells your express app "when there is a get request to the base url, go ahead and expose this directory, and by default respond with the contents of an index.html file if present"

Comment: I want to use res.sendFile() method inside app.get('/')

Comment: that's fine. but the recommended way in the express docs is `express.static`, as shown in the link in my answer